# How to get id of button clicked in mapped loop in React

Tags: jquery, reactjs, loops, button

Hi I've been trying to get the id of mapped buttons in react and pass it to a variable in my state.

This is my code

```
render() {

    let {firstpost, selectedGroup} = this.state;
    let visibleModal = this.showModal;

    var groupList = firstpost.map(function(item, i){

    return (
        <li key={i}>
        <div >
        <button id={myButton+[i]} onClick={visibleModal}>
                btn{firstpost[i]}
            </button>

        </div>
        </li>
    )
    });
return (
    <div>
        {groupList}
         <Modal
                width={'50%'}
                visible={visible}
                onCancel={this.handleCancel}
                footer= {null}
            >

                <Form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
                    <span>Are you sure you want to click</span>
                    <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit" style={{margin: '0 0 0 50%'}}>click</Button>
                </Form>

            </Modal>
    </div>
```

I tried using Jquery like so in my componentsWillMount

```
let _this = this;
$(":button").click(function (event) {
        _this.setState({idName: $(this).attr('id')});
    });
```

and I also tried

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName("button");
var buttonsCount = buttons.length;
for (var i = 0; i <= buttonsCount; i += 1) {
buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
    _this.setState({idName:this.id});
};
}​
```

But that didn't seem to work and I'm not sure of how else to go about it.
Any ideas would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Dom is not working 100% with react js. so dont use id for identify item.  pass id directly to function params or if you still need to find item then use refs in react js

Answer (score 3):

If you only want to update the state `idName`, and do not need reference to each button, you may set state in `onClick` callback of the button:

```
var groupList = firstpost.map((item, i) => 
    <li key={i}>
        <div >
            <button onClick={(e) => {
                        this.setState({idName: `myButton${i}`})
                    }}>
                btn{item}
            </button>
        </div>
    </li>
);
```

By the way, be careful of using just index as `key`. It can lead to unpredictable rendering issue, because a key is the only thing React uses to identify DOM elements. It is better to assign a unique id to each item in your list and use it as `key`.
[Here](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318) and [here](https://medium.com/@vraa/why-using-an-index-as-key-in-react-is-probably-a-bad-idea-7543de68b17c) are some articles you may find useful explaining this issue.